# Tag completion using ido during org-capture

Tags: org-mode, completion

I would like to quickly use one of the already used tags when taking notes quickly using `org-capture`.

There is one [inbuilt way](http://orgmode.org/manual/Completion.html) of using `M-TAB` after `:` but there are 2 issues with that:

- It does not work in the narrowed down Capture buffer.. I need to widen it first.
- I would like to have a "list" completion interface so that I can pick one of the existing tags from the minibuffer.. think of `imenu`/`ido`/`ivy`.

Here is a typical use case (using my bindings for the example workflow):

1. `C-c c j` to make a quick `org-capture` entry in my journal.org
2. Type heading
3. Hit `C-c C-q` to enter a tag
4. Start typing the tag (and at this point I would like the minibuffer to show a list of tags that match with what I already typed in the minibuffer).

   - Pick one from the list by hitting `RET` if I want to reuse a tag, OR
   - If that exact tag doesn't already exist, create it when I hit `RET`

Currently, in step 4, if I want to use one of the already used tags, there is no way for me to ensure if I am doing so or creating a new tag with slight variation of that old tag.

For example: I might already have had a heading with a tag `PRJ_v1` in the past and I intend to make a new heading with the same tag. But by mistake I end up creating a new tag called `PRJ_r1` (because I did not remember if the original tag was `PRJ_v1` or `PRJ_r1`). I would like to prevent such tag duplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I posted that question, I have switched to using the [`ivy`/`counsel`](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper) family of packages for this purpose (instead of `ido`).

After installing the `counsel` package from Melpa, and below piece of code in my emacs init, auto-completing org tags has become a breeze all-over org: In the Capture buffer, in regular org buffers and even in `org-agenda`.

```el
(require 'counsel)
(with-eval-after-load 'org
  (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-q") #'counsel-org-tag))
(with-eval-after-load 'org-agenda
  (define-key org-agenda-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-q") #'counsel-org-tag-agenda))
```

Here is what I get in my tag completion after hitting `C-c C-q` in the Capture buffer and then searching for tags beginning with the letter `b` (`^b`):

[image]

---

`counsel` basically uses the `ivy` package for backend (which is like `ido-vertical-mode` broadly speaking). You can learn more about Counsel completion from the package author's [blog post](http://oremacs.com/2015/04/09/counsel-completion/).

Answer (score 2):

Would it work to use the `%^g` element in your template to prompt for a tag at a specific position within the template? In one of mine, I use:

```
(add-to-list 'org-capture-templates
         `("j" "Journal" entry
           (file+datetree "journal.org" "Journal")
           "* %^{Plan} %^g\n%?\n"
           :kill-buffer t))
```

which prompts for a tag after prompting for a headline, then lets me type in the rest of the entry in the capture buffer. As far as I can tell, it picks up the tags from the journal.org file appropriately for completion.

The doc in http://orgmode.org/manual/Template-expansion.html describes `%^g` as "Prompt for tags, with completion on tags in target file." There is also `%^G` to prompt for tags from all agenda files.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. I was not aware of the `%^g` and `%^G` fields earlier.